# Why are my links are unclickable on my main page but are clickable on the actual page of the post?

Tags: css, hyperlink, z-index

I assume it is something to do with one of my z-indexs but I can't seem to work it out? They are clearly showing up as links as they have changed colour but they are unclickable. Here's my page: http://shelbyleighloves.blogspot.co.uk

Comment: See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Change the postition-Attribuete from the "date-header" Class from relative to absolute. That should solve your problem.

```
  date-header {
        margin: 0px 0px -10px 210px;
        border: 5px sold white;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1;
    }
```

Comment: I changed the height of the date-header and that seemed to do the trick, thank you!